# Jquery chosen not working in Flaty template

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-chosen

I have a form , in which i'm using flaty template. The chosen multiple select working in a page , but on another page its not working.

Need help with immediate effects. [image]

Comment: You do not give the code which sometimes work nor do you give any context and as to what might be the difference. Thus your question cannot be answered, less so immediately.

Comment: <div class="form-group">
     <label class="col-sm-3 col-lg-3 control-label">
         Category Name<span>*</span>
     </label>
     <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-9 controls">
         <select name="Category_Id[]" id="Category_Id" class="form-control chosen" data-placeholder="Select Category" tabindex="-1"  multiple="multiple">
      <option value="">Select</option>

Comment: Add those details by editing the question. Not by posting in the comments

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("#select_id").chosen({ width: "350px"});
```

**Use this**

```
<style>
.chosen-container { width: 220px !important; }
</style>
```